# Issue in finding palindrome and concatenating string

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to programming and doing the string palindrome and concatenation program in HTML and JavaScript.

```js
function perform() {
  var a = document.getElementById("t1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("t2").value;

  if (document.getElementById('p1').checked) {
    if (a === a.split("").reverse().join("")) {
      document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = a + " is a Palindrome";
    }
  } else if (document.getElementById('p2').checked) {
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = a + " " + b;
  }
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', perform);
```

```html
Enter First String <input type="text" id="t1"><br>
Enter Second String <input type="text" id="t2"><br><br>

<input type="radio" name="r" id="p1"> Palindrome <br>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="p2"> Concatenate <br>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="p3"> Length <br>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="p4"> Compare <br>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="p5"> Substring position <br>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="p6"> IndexOf <br>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="p7"> Lowercase <br>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="p8"> Uppercase <br><br>
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="d">
```

Neither palindrome nor concatenation code is working in my code.

Any changes suggested would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you had some string without the " " marks around them, this caused the code to fail.

Secondly, with some minor adjustments, the code works just fine.

Take a look: (at the end of the code, you find a working link to a jsFiddle example)

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script>
      function perform() {
        var a = document.getElementById("t1").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("t2").value;

        if (document.getElementById('p1').checked) {
          var aReversed = a.split("").reverse().join("");
          if (a == aReversed) {
            document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = a + " is a Palindrome";
          } else {
          document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = a +  " is not a Palindrome";
          }

        } else if (document.getElementById('p2').checked) {
          document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = a + " " + b;
        }

      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    Enter First String
    <input type="text" id="t1">
    <br>
    <br> Enter Second String
    <input type="text" id="t2">
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="r" id="p1"> Palindrome
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="p2"> Concatenate
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="p3"> Length
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="p4"> Compare
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="p5"> Substring position
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="p6"> IndexOf
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="p7"> Lowercase
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="p8"> Uppercase
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="perform()" value="Submit">
    <div id="d">

  </body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xuag2z8p/3/

Best Regards :)

Comment: Thanks, could you advise what were the minow adjustment as I want to understand where I went wrong and not simply copy paste the code.

Comment: Well, apart the missing quote marks, basically this worked fine, however i did some refactoring:
1. You dont have to do this : a + " " + "some text bla bla". Insert the space like this a + " some text bla bla"
2. I created a variable for the reversed value, this way you can debug more easily.
3. I also write out when something is not a palindrome, its more informative.
I think thats all. :)